# Smooth Transition between tiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

As you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kmHZt/10/), when you use the arrow keys to move the red square around, the transition between tiles is very choppy and it just does not look good.

I am wondering if there is a way to have a smooth transition between tiles so it looks like one smooth motion?

```
var canvas, context, board, imageObj, tiles, board, display;
var NUM_OF_TILES = 2;

// viewport
var vX = 0,
    vY = 0,
    vWidth = 15,
    vHeight = 10;

var playerX = 0,
    playerY = 0;

var worldWidth = 29,
    worldHeight = 19;

function loadMap(map) {
    if (map == 1) {
        return [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {


    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.tabIndex = 0;
    canvas.focus();
    canvas.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        var key = null;
        switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            // Left
            if (playerX > 0) playerX--;
            break;
        case 38:
            // Up
            if (playerY > 0) playerY--;
            break;
        case 39:
            // Right
            if (playerX < worldWidth) playerX++;
            break;
        case 40:
            // Down
            if (playerY < worldHeight) playerY++;
            break;
        }
        // Okay! The player is done moving, now we have to determine the "best" viewport.
        // Ideally the viewport centers the player,
        // but if its too close to an edge we'll have to deal with that edge

        vX = playerX - Math.floor(0.5 * vWidth);
        if (vX < 0) vX = 0;
        if (vX+vWidth > worldWidth) vX = worldWidth - vWidth;


        vY = playerY - Math.floor(0.5 * vHeight);
        if (vY < 0) vY = 0;
        if (vY+vHeight > worldHeight) vY = worldHeight - vHeight;


        draw();
    }, false);

    var board = [];

    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 352;

    board = loadMap(1);
    imageObj = new Image();
    tiles = [];

    var loadedImagesCount = 0;
    for (x = 0; x <= NUM_OF_TILES; x++) {
        var imageObj = new Image(); // new instance for each image
        imageObj.src = "http://mystikrpg.com/canvas/img/tiles/t" + x + ".png";

        imageObj.onload = function() {
            // console.log("Added tile ... "+loadedImagesCount);
            loadedImagesCount++;
            if (loadedImagesCount == NUM_OF_TILES) {
                // Onces all tiles are loaded ...
                // We paint the map
                draw();
            }
        };
        tiles.push(imageObj);
    }


    function draw() {
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (y = 0; y <= vHeight; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x <= vWidth; x++) {
                theX = x * 32;
                theY = y * 32;
                context.drawImage(tiles[board[y+vY][x+vX]], theX, theY, 32, 32);
            }
        }
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.fillRect((playerX-vX)*32, (playerY-vY)*32, 32, 32);
    }
});
```

Comment: In answer to your question: yes.

Comment: You need to treat the position of your character not in tiles but in pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around a little bit and got something working:

```
    case 39:
       // Right
       if (playerX < worldWidth) {
           var start = playerX;
           var end   = Math.round(playerX + 1);
           $({ i : start }).animate({ i: end}, {
                duration: 400,
                step: function(now) {
                   playerX = now;
                   draw();
                }
            });
        }
        break;
```

I use the jquery animate function in order to interpolate between the values. I realized the draw function is called only once, in order to get an animation i had to call it every step.

In order to avoid errors on the re-centering use `Math.round()` there too.

```
    vX = Math.round(playerX) - Math.floor(0.5 * vWidth);
    if (vX < 0) vX = 0;
    if (vX+vWidth > worldWidth) vX = worldWidth - vWidth;


    vY = Math.round(playerY) - Math.floor(0.5 * vHeight);
    if (vY < 0) vY = 0;
    if (vY+vHeight > worldHeight) vY = worldHeight - vHeight;
```

Of course you have to do additional work, e.g. the start and stop points could vary this way. As suggested you maybe should use pixel positions for your char instead of tiles. But i dont know your intent.

You can avoid the getting stuck on keydown by checking if the tile is in a "full" position by checking

```
if (playerY < worldHeight && playerY % 1 == 0) {...
```

Comment: thanks, but why am I getting a blank screen if I move the square too fast?

Comment: What should happen if you keep the key pressed? This is kind of a problem, if you keep the key down it will trigger the key down event all the time and the animation can't keep track of this fast change